Numpy dependency error when using sklearn-1.5:10 environment to deploy Azure ML model
I'm using the sklearn-1.5(version 10) environment to deploy a ML model which uses sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier. When deploying the endpoint I keep running into dependency issues with numpy.
I specifically get the following error:
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. 
Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

How can I fix this?
I tried using pip to force install the correct packages (as specified in the environment) in the train.py code:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 
                       "numpy==1.22.0", 
                       "pandas==1.5.3", 
                       "scipy==1.8.0", 
                       "matplotlib==3.5.3", 
                       "scikit-image==0.19.3", 
                       "contourpy==1.0.7", 
                       "azure-storage-blob==12.19.0", 
                       "--force-reinstall"])

but this has made no difference.

Did you altered requirment.txt and conda dependencies?

@JayashankarGS I didn't alter any requirements or dependencies in the  sklearn-1.5(version 10) environment

Try modifying the requirements.txt with above packages or in conda dependencies.

@JayashankarGS thanks for your comment. I have made a custom environment where the Dockerfile is the same as sklearn 1.5:10, and modified the conda dependencies to:
channels:

conda-forge
anaconda
dependencies:
python=3.10
pip=21.3.1
pandas==2.1.1
scipy=1.11.2
numpy==1.23.5

Still get the same error when deploying the endpoint however.
